# Application insights grouping deployments when generating map

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-application-insights, azure-aks

Take a look at this development environment map generated by application insights:
[image]

What you are actually looking at are actually 26 deployments on the same AKS and Namespace, but the map leads you into believing that there are 26 pods of the same deployment!

The map should look like this:
[image]

How can I "break" that central node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Map groups based on RoleName property. If you include (through, for instance, TelemetryInitializer) a deployment id then you'll see 26 different nodes.